# using curl commands after launching server with node.js

Tags: node.js, curl

How do you run curl commands after launching a node.js application from the terminal?

I'm following some example from the book Node.js in Action and it has you launch the server and then POST some data via curl -d.

In the expected output sections, it has some curl commands to run, but after launching my application, I don't even see a '$', where as the sample output shows the commands entered after a '$'. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because NodeJS doesn't detach from the shell. Either open a new terminal or, in most Linux shells, you can press `ctrl+z` to push NodeJS to the background.